# Unable to insert image in my Access Database

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, c#-4.0

Well I have a simple MS Access database where the connection is fine but I keep getting the error

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO Statement

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   byte[] picbyte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imgFile);
   try
   {
      conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
      conn.Open();
      sqlcom = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Image (Img) values (@Img)", conn);
      sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", picbyte);
      sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
      conn.Close();
   }
}
```

My table's name is `Image` and the columns are `ImgId` (Autonumber) and `Img` (OLE Object)

Comment: Can you post the full error you received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem may occur if your database table contains column names that use Microsoft Jet 4.0 reserved words, can you try to change your table name?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
byte[] picbyte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imgFile);
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Image] (Img) VALUES (@Img)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", picbyte);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your table name (`IMAGE`) is data type. In order to escape that, you have to use brackets `[ ]`.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Image] (Img) VALUES (@Img)";
```